# Propel 1.6 i18n with Symfony2 forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, internationalization, propel

Has anyone here used Propel's i18n behaviour with Symfony2? I can't seem to find anything about this, and I don't know how to start.

I'm looking forward to use Symfony2 forms with Propel 1.6 i18n, and I can't find any example on how to put this all together.

Comment: I did a quick search, and couldn't find anything either. You could grep the Symfony and Propel 1.6 Symfony plugin to see if there are any unit tests that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has been done for i18n with Propel and Symfony2 yet, but there is a work in progress here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5032.